# Where to provide try catch block

Tags: java

I am trying to copy files from windows server1 to another windows server2 and not sure where to put the try catch block. I want to inform the user whenver windows server1 or windows server2 shuts down while copying process is ongoing either throught a popup or displaying in a textArea and here is my swingworker code. Thanks in advance

```
class CopyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer>
{
    private File source;
    private File target;
    private long totalBytes = 0;
    private long copiedBytes = 0;

    public CopyTask(File src, File dest)
    {
        this.source = src;
        this.target = dest;


        progressAll.setValue(0);
        progressCurrent.setValue(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        ta.append("Retrieving info ... ");

        retrieveTotalBytes(source);
        ta.append("Done!\n");

        copyFiles(source, target);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<Integer> chunks)
    {
        for(int i : chunks)
        {
            progressCurrent.setValue(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void done()
    {
        setProgress(100);


    }
    private void retrieveTotalBytes(File sourceFile)
    {
        File[] files = sourceFile.listFiles();
        for(File file : files)
        {
            if(file.isDirectory()) retrieveTotalBytes(file);
            else totalBytes += file.length();
        }
    }

    private void copyFiles(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws IOException
    {

        if(sourceFile.isDirectory())
        {

            if(!targetFile.exists()) targetFile.mkdirs();

            String[] filePaths = sourceFile.list();

            for(String filePath : filePaths)
            {
                File srcFile = new File(sourceFile, filePath);
                File destFile = new File(targetFile, filePath);

                copyFiles(srcFile, destFile);
            }


        }
        else
        {

            ta.append("Copying " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to " + targetFile.getAbsolutePath() ); //appends to textarea
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

            long fileBytes = sourceFile.length();
            long soFar = 0;

            int theByte;

            while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(theByte);

                setProgress((int) (copiedBytes++ * 100 / totalBytes));
                publish((int) (soFar++ * 100 / fileBytes));
            }



            bis.close();
            bos.close();
            publish(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you actually mean both the source and destination of your copy are remote?

Comment: Yes both are in different windows servers, so I have to check if any of the windows server shuts down then an expection has to be thrown to the user a pop up

Answer (score 2):

Where is the line where the exception can happen?  That's the first place I locate any exception.

Generally, if your modules are small, you can wrap the `try` around all the real code in the module and catch the exceptions at the end, especially if the exception is fatal.  Then you can log the exception and return an error message/status to the user.

However, the strategy is different if the exception is not fatal.  In this case you'll have to handle it right where the connection exception is thrown so you can seamlessly resume when the connection returns.  Of course, this is a little more work.

EDIT - you probably want `bis.close()` and `bos.close()` inside a `finally` block to ensure they get closed.  It may be pedantic but it seems prudent.

Comment: Another point would be can my program try to fix the problem by itself or can only the user do something about it. Some examples: connection lost (retry), no route to host (probably wrong hostname), wrong file type (user selected wrong file). Things only the user can handle can be raised to the top. The other exceptions should be handled where they are thrown.